# Warning Notification if specific inbox folder reaches 20 items

Tags: vba, outlook

New on VBA and no idea what to do. I got the logic on my head but can't script the codes.

1. When specific folder on inbox reaches a count of 20 messages it will send a notification to a specific email.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the [NewMailEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863686(v=office.15).aspx) event of the Application class or the [ItemAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869609(v=office.15).aspx) event of the Items class where you can check out the number of items in the specific folder (folder.Items.Count) and send a notification if required.